# Java stackoverflowerror what is the correct stack size to use?

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-overflow

I am running into Java StackOverFlowError upon running a recursive program. The program is correct and the recursion needs to be implemented. I tried to find the current stack size using the command

```
    java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize
```

and this is what i got:

```
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
```

java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

What does this mean? And how can I increase the stacksize and what value should i set? Is it normal to get this error for the above settings?Please help.

Comment: Also have a look at the Fork and Join framework to do your recursive task:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: `The program is correct` - how do you know this if you are getting this exception?

Answer (score 1):

It means the stack size is 1MB (1024KB). And you can increase the thread stack size by passing `-Xss<size>`, for example to set the stack size to 32 MB for each thread:

```
java -Xss32m
```

Usually a stack size of 1MB is enough. For most of the projects I worked on, I rarely need to change the stack size. So quite possibly your code is not correct as you think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a recursive code and it doesn't have code to terminate the recursion then you will eventually get the **stackoverflow error** , no matter how much high is your stack size.

There is nothing which you can do apart from fixing your code, which causes this error.

Comment: You assume there is an infinite recursion. This may not be the case (the OP writes "The program is correct"). Some recursions need more stack than is availbale by default.

Comment: @Henry , its not me who wrote `infinte recursion` its user Harmlezz :) .

Comment: Isn't that just the same as "doesn't have code to terminate the recursion"?

Comment: @Henry Lol , you got it right :p , but without OP providing the code, we cant say code is correct although he claims it and i used `if` at least before my statement :p .

Comment: To clarify, the program does not have an infinite recursion because it works fine for some values. The problem happens only when the number of recursions increase. I'm sorry that I cannot share the code as it is confidential.